# MySQL & c programming language

Tags: mysql, c, windows

When I try to use the following;

`#include <mysql.h>`

I get an error that it is not found in this library.

I've tried to rewrite it as:

`#include <mysql/mysql.h>`

But I keep getting the same error.

[This is problem image](http://postimg.org/image/gvx9ktc97/)

Comment: add compilerflag like -I/usr/local/mysql/include, and please be more specific. What system, how did you install mysql

Comment: You don't have the requisite header file. Don't guess where it is: locate it or download it from http://dev.mysql.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your filesystem to locate the mysql.h file, then use the -I flag with gcc to tell it to look for include files in this directory.  For example, if your mysql.h file is in /usr/include/mysql, your would do:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try #include "mysql.h" that will find mysql.h file from current directory.